# What type of web hosting do I need if I want to run a Node.js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, hosting

I want to build a web app with React for frontend and Node.js for backend. The problem comes when choosing the type of hosting I need. I know that for static files(eg. html with css and js) it's enough to have a standard web hosting, but if I want to have a server running Node.js app, do I need a dedicated server or VPS? Why?

Comment: Yes you need an actual server to run node.js. That's because Node.js can't be run client-side (like JavaScript in your browser). If you don't want to host it on a VPS, you can always go the PaaS route and pay for a service like Heroku. There's virtually limitless options for hosting a node application, but all of them require your code to be hosted on a server in one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can have either. Are you trying to do this professionally for a client or for a side project?

Personally, I use services like Heroku or Netlify (others here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/8-react-application-deployment-and-hosting-options-for-2019-ab4d668309fd). They run builds of node for your app and are free initially.

You can host your app and publish it for no cost at the beginning. However, on something like Heroku, if you don't pay, it takes 5 seconds for your website to wake up. But, this is great for prototyping. It gives you a URL so others can see it. They are basically version control systems that publish what you currently have. So you can just live push your project at any time and it updates your site.

If your prototype is working and you want it to be a fully dedicated app, then you can either pay or find services that host it. I would recommend prototyping first regardless and wouldn't pay until you need to.

Comment: yes, for now it's for a side project, to familiarize with deploying apps, both frontend and backend.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to sway you, use whatever hosting service you want, but if you want to get started, you can try something like: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs